# Am I an Interactive Designer yet?

Tags: portfolio

What kind of portfolio do I need before I can start calling myself an "Interactive Designer"? I currently design websites, and I've been redesigning our company's flagship sites to improve User Experience... but when can I start calling myself an "Interactive/UX Designer"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a government agency that you must apply to to receive permission.  Otherwise, the UX police will come and get you.

Seriously, you can say it now.  Wait...  Ok now.

Welcome to the craft.  Read alot.  Spread the word.  Help train others.  Love the user.

Comment: Ha ha. Wait!? What about fees? Are there yearly fees?

Comment: Good news - some one must reviewed the form because you don't have to fill it out in triplicate anymore.

Comment: There's a secret handshake... oh, wait I'm not supposed to say that.

Comment: The handshake is great - you say ACK, they say SYN.  If you say ACKACK you qualify as an alien in "Mars Attacks" :)

Answer (score 4):

I reckon you can say it once people start paying you for that service. So if you have clients that are buying "interactive design" services from you, you're all set. Mind you, I like Glen's notion of the UX police. I bet they have very nice uniforms.

Answer (score 1):

You've done some, you have been paid for it, so call yourself it, and be prepared to backup the claim that you are an Interactive Designer when questioned.

Oh, and accept some answers???